# how can i get libmemcached for windows?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, dll, memcached, libmemcached

i'm trying to install the memcached extension in my windows localhost: wamp 64 php 5.5.12. see memcached at: https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached (notice that This extension uses libmemcached library)

unfortunately there is not a ready dll for this extension.. so i need to produce the dll myself.

i followed this guide in order to produce a working dll: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild 
(im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to compile)

i get an error when i try to configure (just before the build).
here is the print screen error that i get:

[image]

unfortunately the memcached extension is depended on ['libmemcached library'](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html) which do not officially support windows environment.

i came across this git project. 
https://github.com/moteus/libmemcached-win32
im not sure what can i do with that source file and how can that help me. it seems that this git project is a libmemcached ready to work in windows (for all i know)

do this github project is a ready libmemcached library (if so where is the memcached.lib?)? or how can i produce from this page a memcached.lib file? (or anything that will help me make a working dll for the memcached extension)

would deeply appreciate any help on this.
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is vs2015 lib+dlls 1.0.18 available:

https://github.com/yshurik/libmemcached-win/releases/tag/1.0.18

Also vcxproj is availbale so you can compile it for other versions of msvc.
win32 branch on launchpad is extremely old and has different api from 1.0 version.

Comment: Thank you YShurik! (Шурик?) :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a libmemcached for windows. From the memcached website:

https://code.launchpad.net/~mattn/libmemcached/libmemcached-win32

Comment: not sure. maybe it still in development? the official readme file says they still do not support windows

Comment: The official website says it supports Win, wikipedia says the same, I am not sure what is your point. I wouldn't host a website with memcached on a windows box, but it is possible.